# Need help exporting game that plays sound file

Tags: python, winsound

I was making a Tetris-like game, and I would like my friends to try it so I'm going to export it as an `.exe` file, but I'm playing the track in the background this way:

```
winsound.PlaySound('C:/Users/User/folder/project/tetris/tetrismusic.wav', 
                   winsound.SND_LOOP + winsound.SND_ASYNC)
```

I don't know if there is a way to play the file another way that doesn't involve the path. I've also tried:

```
winsound.Playsound('tetrismusic.wav', winsound.SND_LOOP + winsound.SND_ASYNC))
```

But it gives out an error saying the file can't be played.

Comment: What tool are you using to convert your script into an `.exe`. You should add it a tag to your question (because it matters).

Answer (score 1):

Try putting a `./` before the filename.

`winsound.Playsound('./tetrismusic.wav', winsound.SND_LOOP + winsound.SND_ASYNC))`

Or — alternatively — add the `SND_FILENAME` flag.

`winsound.Playsound('tetrismusic.wav', winsound.SND_LOOP + winsound.SND_ASYNC + winsound.SND_FILENAME))`

Checking the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/winsound.html), it seems the `Playsound` function is assuming that `tetrismusic.wav` is a sound alias.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this solved it!